How to add watermark in wordfile?
I want to add watermark using c#. I am trying to add watermark using c# but when adding watermark as header it adds to all pages of wordfile and when i edit watermark from any page of wordfile watermark is edited in all pages.when watermark add as header It is possible when it happens. I can't achieve this above thing without adding in header like adding watermark to all pages and if i edit watermark from any page and it doesn't change in all pages.
This is the solution I tried to add a watermark to Word.
public class Watermark
{
    private Application wordApp;
    private Document doc;

    public Watermark(Application wordApp, Document doc)
    {
        this.wordApp = wordApp;
        this.doc = doc;
    }

    public void AddCenteredTextWatermark(string watermarkText)
    {
        foreach (Section section in doc.Sections)
        {
            // Access the primary header in each section to add the watermark
            HeaderFooter header = section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];

            // Clear any existing watermark shapes in the header
            foreach (Shape shape in header.Shapes)
            {
                if (shape.Type == MsoShapeType.msoTextEffect)
                {
                    shape.Delete();
                }
            }

            // Add the watermark shape to the header
            Shape watermarkShape = header.Shapes.AddTextEffect(
                MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1,
                watermarkText,
                "Arial", // Font name
                50, // Font size
                MsoTriState.msoTrue, // Bold
                MsoTriState.msoFalse, // Not italic
                0, // Position from the left
                0  // Position from the top
            );

            // Format the watermark appearance
            watermarkShape.Fill.Solid();
            watermarkShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (int)WdColor.wdColorGray25;
            watermarkShape.Line.Visible = MsoTriState.msoFalse;
            watermarkShape.WrapFormat.Type = WdWrapType.wdWrapBehind;
            watermarkShape.Rotation = -45;

            // Center the watermark on the page
            watermarkShape.Left = (float)(doc.PageSetup.PageWidth - watermarkShape.Width) / 2;
            watermarkShape.Top = (float)(doc.PageSetup.PageHeight - watermarkShape.Height) / 2;

            // Set positioning relative to the page
            watermarkShape.RelativeHorizontalPosition = WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionPage;
            watermarkShape.RelativeVerticalPosition = WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionPage;

            // Lock aspect ratio and align text to prevent distortion
            watermarkShape.LockAspectRatio = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
            watermarkShape.TextEffect.Alignment = MsoTextEffectAlignment.msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered;

            // Prevent users from resizing the watermark shape
            watermarkShape.LockAspectRatio = MsoTriState.msoTrue;
        }
    }
}

=>Using this solution it adds the watermark to the wordfile and it is also editable Because its add as header but when I manually remove the header in the wordfile it also removes the watermark because the watermark is added to the header.  Now I expect this solution. first  should not add the watermark as header. And Watermark add to all pages of word file. But not as a header. The second watermark should be editable and when I edit the watermark, the watermark should change in all pages of the wordfile.

Do you know how to do it in the Word UI? If you do, create a file that doesn't have the watermark in Word. Save it, and make a copy. Then use the OpenXML Productivity Tool to diff those two files and see how to code it up.

Well, of course it adds it to the header. What do you think HeaderFooter header = section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary]; mean? section.Headers should tell you that it's adding it to the header - that's why it says Headers.

Why specifically do you want a watermark?

Provide another code for achive my requirments. i put my code that i use and it is add watermark as header. if u know another solution For Achive those things by another way so give me .

I think that's just how you show watermarks in Word. Only the header and footer are visible on all pages, so that's where you add it. I'm afraid you are out of luck if you wish to delete your header and keep the watermark.

Why specifically do you want a watermark?
